# Serilog RollingFile sinks Create folder named with date

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I am in process of moving from NLog to serilog. In NLog I could do the following:

```
logs/20170101/log-Debug.log
logs/20170101/log-Error.log
logs/20170101/log-Info.log
```

i.e. date based folder names for my logs. Is there a way to achive same in Serilog?

Thanks

Comment: I can't think of a way to achieve this at present, but raised https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map/issues/1 as one possible future implementation.

Comment: Nice Thanks @NicholasBlumhardt Great product btw !

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to your folder naming issue?? i've just started with serilog today (yes - a bit behind the curve) and have an identical issue.. cheers